# Codeigniter does not show Image

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Sorry to ask this question as I am now stagnant to solve this issue. 
I search the net but I dont know where I made a mistake.

What I am doing is to write text into an existing image using codeigniter.

Here's my code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
$imgpath = base_url() . 'assets/images/birform2316.jpg';
$img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$font_path = base_url() . 'assets/fonts/arial.ttf';
imagettftext($img, 100, 0, 300, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

However, when I displayed it, it shows this one:
[image]

However, when I ran the same code outside codeigniter, I got the desired result
like this one below:
[image]

Is there any configurations I missed in codeigniter?

By the way, my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is nothing to do show image with .htaccess file. It seems like your image is not saving in the upload folder or if you are able to upload the image in the upload folder then check for the file permission. If the image is not saving in the folder try this tutorial for more on file upload http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: did you checked the image path ? may be it's broken. mouse over the image. will show you the image path. check to see if its absolute path.

Comment: base_url returns http:// path, which is a url ... try using an actual path for your image.